# parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "golang.org/x/lint"

Tags: go

I have a package that I've uploaded to Github and am I am go getting the package on another server and keep getting the error:

> go: github.com/golang/lint@v0.0.0-20190313153728-d0100b6bd8b3: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "golang.org/x/lint"

I've deleted `go.mod`, `go.sum` and the vendor directory and updated all packages using

```
go get -u ./...
```

`golang.org/x/lint` is not in `go.mod` or `go.sum` or vendor directory yet I still get the error when trying to go get the package on my other server.

Comment: Try `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint` from your server

Comment: getting same error

Comment: please try this workaround `go mod edit -replace github.com/golang/lint@latest=golang.org/x/lint@latest` as it's explained here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30831#issuecomment-478314143

Comment: I had GO111MODULE=on on my server...turned it to off and it worked. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, May 2021 (two years later) `x/lint` is fully deprecated. See [issue 38968](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38968#issuecomment-835585422) and [CL 318190](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/build/+/318190/).

Your error was seen in [issue 32412](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32412) (related to [issue 27900](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27900)).
And [`go get -u`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26902) has been fixed ([CL 174099](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/174099/) "make `get -u` upgrade only modules providing packages")